# Multiple Nested Aggregations in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I have multiple Hosts -->  multiple URL  -->,  and I want to do two aggregations on url basis. One is for response code, and the other is for percentile of response time.

I am trying to do these the same but it throws exception:

> Found two sub aggregation method

My query:

```
"aggs" : {
    "host" : {  "terms" : { "field" : "hostname" },
    "aggs":{
    "request": {  "terms":{  "field" : "request" },
    "aggs":{
        "status" : { "terms" : { "field" : "responsecode" }}},
        "aggs":{
           "percen" : { "percentiles" : { "field" : "response_time", "percents" : [50,75,90,95,99] }},
           "avrg" : { "avg" : { "field" : "response_time" } 
}}}}}}
```

Does Elastic Search Only support nested aggregation on one field at a time?

Comment: YES you can make multiple nested aggs at same time. this is not nested syntax for me. what is your mapping

Answer (score 0):

One of your sub-aggregations is not properly nested in your query, you need to remove a few braces (see below) depending on where you want the `percen` and `avrg` aggregations to be contained:

```
"aggs" : {
    "host" : {  "terms" : { "field" : "hostname" },
    "aggs":{
    "request": {  "terms":{  "field" : "request" },
    "aggs":{
        "status" : { "terms" : { "field" : "responsecode" }}},
                                                           ^^
                                                           ||
                                                remove these two braces

        "aggs":{
           "percen" : { "percentiles" : { "field" : "response_time", "percents" : [50,75,90,95,99] }},
           "avrg" : { "avg" : { "field" : "response_time" } 
}}}}}}
```

Comment: sorry, I was on leave for few days, so unable to look into it.. 
@Val,  Yes, it would work, but it will calculate the percentiles and avrg per status_code. i.e.  It will do aggregation by hostname->request->responsecode-> {percentiles, avrg}
What i have to do, calculate percentiles and avg on request not on responsecode  i.e.
It will do aggregation by hostname->request-> {responsecode, percentiles, avrg}